# The "&" in the title font doesn't look anything like an ampserand

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

This is supposed to read:

> Admin > Upcoming & Current Community Events.

I don't know what the symbol is in there, but it certainly doesn't look like "&".

Comment: Wow, that's a weird symbol to replace.

Comment: The "&" has been replaced by the word "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is will be fixed in the next build.  I blame [Jin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) and his wonky fonts.